# How to extract the actual quote and author from the quotations using regex?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm scraping quotations from Twitter, and from those quotations I want to separate the actual quote from its author.

How can I accomplish this if the tweets are not uniformly formatted?

I am new on regex, but here's my best try on regex101 https://regex101.com/r/m3WtmX/5.

And below is the code I have, I want each loop to print `sre.SRE_Match object`, but the last one prints `None`.

```py
import re

QUOTE_PATTERN = re.compile(r'^(?P<actual_quote>.*)\s+?-\s*(?P<author>.*)$')

# actual_quote is separated from author by space and dash
format_1 = "Any form of exercise, if pursued continuously, will help train us in perseverance -Mao Tse-Tung"

# separated by one space, dash and another space
format_2 = "Any form of exercise, if pursued continuously, will help train us in perseverance - Mao Tse-Tung"

# actual_quote is surrounded with double quotes character and
# is separated from author by space, dash and another space
format_3 = '"Any form of exercise, if pursued continuously, will help train us in perseverance" - Mao Tse-Tung'

# separated only with dash (no space)
format_4 = "Any form of exercise, if pursued continuously, will help train us in perseverance-Mao Tse-Tung"

for format in [format_1, format_2, format_3, format_4]:
    print(QUOTE_PATTERN.match(format))
```

Comment: It might be hard to write a single pattern which can cover all your edge cases.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I expect that answer :/. It's because of the author having the dash, right?

Comment: Yes, and I don't see any obvious fool-proof way to discern a dash as separator from dash as part of someone's last name.

Comment: [Chin-Ning Chu](https://twitter.com/GreatestQuotes/status/862673868841943040) and [Mao Tse-Tung](https://twitter.com/GreatestQuotes/status/1014151587386839042) has. BTW thank you.

Comment: Do you want to keep " in actual_quote group?

Comment: It also gets really tricky if there is a dash character in quote itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really tricky, since the structure of this data is not **regular**.

Getting all characters of first group before dash in non-greedy way works with quotes you've provided.

```
^(?P<actual_quote>.*?)-(?P<author>.*)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/rcGzzK/2

If you don't wanna include extra spaces:

```
^(?P<actual_quote>.*?)\s*-\s*(?P<author>.*)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/rcGzzK/3

Unfortunately if there are any dashes in quote itself, then above regular expressions won't work.

Comment: +1 for the feedback, though this does not solve my problem. I settled on a more specific and stricter pattern, I'm now happy with `[\"']{0,1}([A-Z].*[\.!?])[\"']{0,1}\s*?[-~]\s*(.*)$`. Thanks anyway :)